# How to check if a report has translations or not?

Tags: abap

I have a report which I wrote translations to different languages, but now I have moved it to a system in which I don't have authorizations to write translations.

This way, the report works only in English: all the Text Symbols don't work if the user accesses the system in another language.

With this in mind, is it possible to write something in the `load-of-program` event to check if translations exist or not, and if not, set `SY-LANGU` to English?

By now, I have a simple `if sy-langu <> 'E'. sy-langu = 'E'. endif.` ("E" for English)

It works fine, but regardless, I'd still like to have a way to find out if there are translations, and only then set it to English.

Comment: SAP recommends not changing the values of system fields: instead of changing `SY-LANGU`, use `SET LOCALE LANGUAGE` instead for the same effect. I have updated your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text Symbols are part of [Text Elements](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentext_element_glosry.htm) which are part of multilingual Text Pools of the program.

1) Use `READ TEXTPOOL` to get the Text Elements in another language:

> "**[READ TEXTPOOL](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapread_textpool.htm)**. This statement reads the text elements of the text pool of the language specified in lang and the program specified in prog from the repository and places them into the internal table itab."

```
data itab type standard table of textpool.
READ TEXTPOOL prog INTO itab LANGUAGE lang.
```

2) Either use the secondary language or use `SET LANGUAGE` to change the language of the text elements as explained in the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentext_pool.htm):

> "When a program is loaded into an internal session, the text elements of the text pool of the logon language are imported by default. If this text pool does not exist, the text pool of the **[secondary language](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abensecondary_language_glosry.htm)** in AS ABAP is used. If none of these text pools exists, an empty text pool without text elements is loaded."
>
> "When the program is executed, the text pool of a different language can be loaded using the statement **[SET LANGUAGE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapset_language.htm)**."

## Solution

If using the secondary language is not satisfying, use this code:

```
LOAD-OF-PROGRAM.
  constants lc_english    type sylangu value `E`.
  data lt_text_symbols    type standard table of textpool.

  read textpool sy-repid into lt_text_symbols language sy-langu.

  if sy-subrc <> 0.
    SET LANGUAGE lc_english.
  endif.
```

PS:

- Profile parameters can be viewed via transaction code `RZ11` (secondary language `zcsa/second_language`).
- Get used with `if sy-subrc <> 0` rather than `if lines( lt_text_symbols ) = 0.` because in some other situations, if `lt_text_symbols` contains something before `READ TEXTPOOL`, its content is not cleared if there's no Text Pool in the requested language.
- Inside the `LOAD-OF-PROGRAM` event, prefer using `sy-repid` over `sy-cprog`, although technically they contain the same at that moment, because the latter has another [meaning](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abensystem_fields.htm):

  > "In externally called procedures, the name of the calling program; otherwise the name of the current program. If an externally called procedure calls another external procedure, sy-cprog contains the name of the master program, and is not set to the name of the master program of the subsequent calling program."
- Don't change the value of `sy-langu`, dixit [System Fields](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abensystem_fields.htm):

  > "they should be used only for reads"
- If you want to change `sy-langu`, use [SET LOCALE LANGUAGE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapset_locale.htm). It has other effects, read the documentation carefully. **Don't confuse** it with SET LANGUAGE.